# Declaración IF con transacciones

Tags: sql-server

Me surgió una duda con respecto al uso de la declaración If en transacciones con `T-SQL`.

Pasa que tengo un stored procedure con distintas declaraciones hechas, sobre todo MERGE:

```sql
merge into MM_MATERIAL target
            using #tbl_stock_almacen_web source
            on target.CodAlmacen = source.CodAlmacen
                and target.NroProducto = source.NroProducto
            when not matched
            then insert(Empresa,TipoMaterial,GrupoArticulo,Codigo,Descripcion,UnidadMedida,PesoNeto,PesoBruto,
                        Activo,ProductoControlado,UsuarioRegistro,FechaRegistro,NroProducto,CodProducto,CodAlmacen)
            values(1,2,1,'01', source.DescProducto, iif(@id_unidad_medida_validacion = 0,1,@id_unidad_medida_validacion),1.0,1.0,
                   1,1,'admin',getdate(),source.NroProducto,source.CodProducto,source.CodAlmacen)
            output $action into @table_output_merge(accion_ultima);

            if (select top 1 lower(accion_ultima) from @table_output_merge) = 'insert' begin
                set @id_mm_material_for_all = ident_current('MM_MATERIAL')
            end
            else begin
                select @id_mm_material_for_all = Material
                from MM_MATERIAL
                where CodAlmacen = @cod_almacen_xml and NroProducto = @nro_producto_xml
            end

            if @id_mm_material_for_all is null begin
                set @ok = -1
                set @response = N'IDMaterial tiene nulo como valor.(2)'
                goto terminar
            end
-- .... 

 terminar:
        select @ok 'Ok',
               @response 'Response'

        if @@trancount > 0
            if @ok = 0
                commit tran
            if @ok < 0
                rollback tran
```

Como se ve en el script, LUEGO de hacer el MERGE tengo que verificar que una variable `Id_mm_material_for_all` tenga algún valor asociado, de lo contrario caigo en el goto y termina el proceso.

El tema viene en los últimos If, tengo la duda si está bien hecho de esa forma para hacer un `ROLLBACK`; es decir, con un IF saber si la variable Ok es distinta de 0 o es igual a 0 para saber si es `COMMIT` o `ROLLBACK`.

Si no está bien, qué otra 'técnica' o 'tip' funcionaría en estos casos?

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour], leas [ask] y [example]. ¿Estás obteniendo algún error? O necesitas una opinión sobre tu código?

Comment: Lo que estás pidiendo es una opinión, que no es algo que entre dentro del formato de pregunta del sitio. De todas formas te doy la mía: lo que estas haciendo es lo habitual cuando se trata de errores controlados, se controla algo y se hace un goto a un código de salida del SP (donde eventualmente se "rollbaquea") , SQL no ofrece ninguna otra estructura de control. Como consejo extra, minimiza cualquier código que tengas entre el control y el roll back, para acortar tiempos de transacciones abiertas.

Comment: Eventualmente puede que quieras controlar los errores no controlados, por ejemplo una clave duplicada o cualquier error de la base, y rolbaquear explicítamente, en cuyo caso revisa el uso del bloque try/catch

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pasa es que necesitas utilizar `BEGIN...END` para agrupar múltiples instrucciones dentro de una condición.

```
    if @@trancount > 0
    BEGIN
        if @ok = 0
            commit tran
        if @ok < 0
            rollback tran
    END
```

Sin embargo, para manejar errores personalizados, es mejor usar `TRY...CATCH...` y `THROW`.

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    MERGE INTO MM_MATERIAL            target
    USING      #tbl_stock_almacen_web source ON target.CodAlmacen  = source.CodAlmacen
                                            AND target.NroProducto = source.NroProducto
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
        INSERT( Empresa,
                TipoMaterial,
                GrupoArticulo,
                Codigo,
                Descripcion,
                UnidadMedida,
                PesoNeto,
                PesoBruto,
                Activo,
                ProductoControlado,
                UsuarioRegistro,
                FechaRegistro,
                NroProducto,
                CodProducto,
                CodAlmacen)
        VALUES( 1,
                2,
                1,
                '01', 
                source.DescProducto, 
                IIF( @id_unidad_medida_validacion = 0, 1, @id_unidad_medida_validacion),
                1.0,
                1.0,
                1,
                1,
                'admin',
                GETDATE(),
                source.NroProducto,
                source.CodProducto,
                source.CodAlmacen)
        OUTPUT $action INTO @table_output_merge(accion_ultima);

    IF (SELECT TOP 1 LOWER(accion_ultima) FROM @table_output_merge) = 'insert' 
    BEGIN
        SET @id_mm_material_for_all = IDENT_CURRENT('MM_MATERIAL');
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
        SELECT @id_mm_material_for_all = Material
        FROM    MM_MATERIAL
        WHERE   CodAlmacen = @cod_almacen_xml 
        AND     NroProducto = @nro_producto_xml;
    END

    IF @id_mm_material_for_all IS NULL 
    BEGIN
        THROW 50001, N'IDMaterial tiene nulo como valor.(2)', 1;
    END

    -- .... 

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER()   AS ResponseId,
            ERROR_MESSAGE() AS Response;
END CATCH;
```

Comment: Cuando se genera el Throw, entiendo que cae en el catch y el error_message() devolverá el mensaje colocado en el Throw? En este caso 'IDMaterial...'? o no?

Comment: Así es, en el THROW es mucho más fácil generar mensajes de error. Otra opción es usar RAISEERROR().

Comment: Entiendo, gracias por la info, esto es muy útil para hacer rollback a toda la transacción y evitar registros no deseados.